# How to display counting for each post in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below works fine and display post records successfully.

Now I need to display post counter for each post based on `post id(pid)`
but I am having error

```
this.state.post.counter is undefined
```

Here is what I have added

```
 {this.state.post.counter.res.map((co, c) => (
<li key={c}>
{co.counting}
              </li>

))}
```

How do I display counting where counting pid matches the pid of the post records?

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {

//function Application() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

post: {"results": 
[
{"desc": "my first post", "pid": "101"},
{"desc": "my second post", "pid": "102"},
{"desc": "my 3rd post", "pid": "103"},

]},

counter: {"res": 
[
{"counting": "1000", "pid": "101"},
{"counting": "5600", "pid": "102"},
{"counting": "340", "pid": "103"},

]}


    };

  }




  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.post.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.pid} - {obj.desc}

               
 {this.state.post.counter.res.map((co, c) => (
<li key={c}>
{co.counting}
              </li>

))}

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access `this.state.post.counter.res` which doesn't exist. You're looking for `this.state.counter.res` instead.

Change `this.state.post.counter.res.map((co, c) => ...` to `this.state.counter.res.map((co, c) => ...`

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bardeen-m2fm8?file=/src/App.js) with a working example of your app.

**EDIT**

In order to render the correct `counting` value that's associated to each post by the `pid` property, you can write the following function:

```
getCounterByPid = pid => {
    const resIndex = this.state.counter.res.findIndex(el => pid === el.pid);
    return this.state.counter.res[resIndex].counting;
};
```

and then return it in your JSX as follows:

```
<ul>
   {this.state.post.results.map((obj, i) => (
      <li key={i}>
         {obj.pid} - {obj.desc}
         <span> Counting {this.getCounterByPid(obj.pid)}</span>
       </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-galileo-126eh?file=/src/App.js) containing the edited code.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  what am trying to achieve is that for instance  my first post should show counting 1000 based on its pid, my second post will have counting 5600 etc. i need to display counting where its pid matches the pid of the post

Comment: Ah, I see. That was unclear to me. I will update my example and then you can tell me if it's what you're looking for

Comment: How's [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-galileo-126eh?file=/src/App.js)? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks alot. that is it. its working now. you can update it as correct answer.